# Codeigniter ignored the WHERE condition in update query

Tags: php, codeigniter

We have faced a critical issue while updating 1 record for a table. Update query has updated to all 22k records instead of 1 record. Because WHERE condition was missed from the query.

Application is running on PHP 5 and Codeigniter 2.0.3. We tried to replicate the issue but we failed to do that.

This logic is there from long time and till now its working properly. But at some particular time this query has failed to add WHERE condition and updated to all the records in table

We have written query logic as below

```
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update($this->table_name, $attributes);
```

We are providing $id as integer value. Ex: 2 or 5 or 100 like that

In application log we got the query

```
UPDATE `users` SET `status` = 1, `updated_by` = 'system'
```

Expected:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `status` = 1, `updated_by` = 'system'  WHERE `users`.`id` = 34.
```

In log there is no error reported.

Please let me know why this failure happened.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your function `$res = $this->update($id, $tableName, array('return' => TRUE));`

Comment: Thank you for reply. We are extending extends CI_Model. Its calling the codeigniter system file

Comment: I mean, the function `$this->update` is from your controller or model?

Comment: Its inside model file

Comment: You need to include that function here to check whether there is any issue

Comment: Its too long to copy paste here

Answer (score 0):

Could  you please do the code in below format

```
$this->db->where('id', 2);
$this->db->update('mytable', $record);
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes i can do and it will work properly. But my concern is why the existing code has failed for some particular scenario (not sure what was the scenario). we are not able to replicate till now

Comment: update($table = '', $set = NULL, $where = NULL, $limit = NULL), this is the function param structure for update query builder , should follow the same, You are given as update($id, $tableName, array('return' => TRUE));